# Oracle json_transform replace particular value on any level

Tags: json, oracle, jsonpath, oracle19c

I need to replace some values in Oracle 19 column that is CLOB with JSON constraint, but cannot find a right way to do it. Json can be big and I suppose regex function on string may not work due to the length restrictions.

My json may have `'locationId'` property at any level with some values. Let's say I have bad value `000` and want to replace it with `111`, so everywhere where is `"locationId":"000"` it becomes `"locationId":"111"`.

I'm trying to use next *json_transform* command:

```
SELECT json_transform('
{
 "a": {
   "locationId":"000"
 }, 
 "b": {
   "locationId":"111", 
   "x": {
     "locationId":"000"
    }
 }
}', REPLACE '$..locationId?(@ == "000")' = '111' IGNORE ON MISSING) 
FROM dual
```

But it returns **unchanged** json, when next query for the same json fetches values to replace properly :

```
SELECT json_query('
{
 "a": {
   "locationId":"000"
 }, 
 "b": {
   "locationId":"111", 
   "x": {
     "locationId":"000"
   }
 }
}', '$..locationId?(@ == "000")' WITH WRAPPER) 
FROM dual
```

Result:
`["000","000"]`

There is no any documentation or examples how to use filters within json_transform, so I'm not sure it's even possible.
Maybe anybody know how to do it? Doesn't matter with json functions or not.

Links I use:

[Oracle Json Path Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/json-path-expressions.html#GUID-2DC05D71-3D62-4A14-855F-76E054032494)

[Oracle json_query](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/function-JSON_QUERY.html#GUID-D64C7BE9-335D-449C-916D-1123539BF1FB)

[Oracle json_transform](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/oracle-sql-function-json_transform.html#GUID-7BED994B-EAA3-4FF0-824D-C12ADAB862C1)

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen that even

```
REPLACE '$..locationId' = '111' IGNORE ON MISSING
```

doesn't change anything ?
(at least in Cloud 21c)

Comment: Yes, so thats why i'm afraid  .. (two dots) may not work for transform. But there is nothing in oracle documentation about limits for json path for transform!

Comment: for the fun you may try

    , REPLACE '$.locationId?(@ == "000")' = '111' IGNORE ON MISSING
    , REPLACE '$.*.locationId?(@ == "000")' = '111' IGNORE ON MISSING
    , REPLACE '$.*.*.locationId?(@ == "000")' = '111' IGNORE ON MISSING
    , REPLACE '$.*.*.*.locationId?(@ == "000")' = '111' IGNORE ON MISSING

since json_transform supports several expressions at once.

Comment: '$.*.locationId?(@ == "000")' = '111' doesn't work either.
Only strict path like '$.a.locationId?(@ == "000")' = '111' works. 
Very limited functionality from Oracle..

Answer (score 1):

It's more complicated:

```
SELECT json_transform('
{
 "locationId" : "000",
 "a": {
   "locationId":"000"
 }, 
 "b": {
   "locationId":"000", 
   "x": {
     "locationId":"000", 
       "y": {
         "locationId":"000"
        }
    }
 }
}'
    , REPLACE '$.locationId?(@ == "000")' = '111' IGNORE ON MISSING
    , REPLACE '$.*.locationId?(@ == "000")' = '111' IGNORE ON MISSING
    , REPLACE '$.*.*.locationId?(@ == "000")' = '111' IGNORE ON MISSING
    , REPLACE '$.*.*.*.locationId?(@ == "000")' = '111' IGNORE ON MISSING
) 
FROM dual;
```

Gives:

```
{"locationId":"111","a":{"locationId":"111"},"b":{"locationId":"111","x":{"locationId":"111","y":{"locationId":"111"}}}}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Oracle 19c. Only strict path without * works

Comment: The latest I posted shows that the behavior also changes according to the content of the sibling nodes. So the best may be to post a bug report, unless somebody else can better explain why.